# how do I create a pull request when all my code is in the main branch?

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-api, pull-request

I wrote all my code to the master branch and I wanted to create a pull request so that some other person can check my code. How do I do that.

Comment: Is there something specific you're looking for? There should be pretty straightforward docs for opening a PR on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create and switch a new branch where you are, then reset `main` to `origin/main`.

```
git switch -c newBranch
git push -u origin newBranch
git branch -f main origin/main
```

Once you have pushed your newBranch, you can on on GitHub and create a PR from that new branch back to the original repository.